# Problems with Eclipse cdt plugin

Tags: eclipse-cdt

I have pre-installed Eclipse Gallileo for Java Developers on my PC and recently downloaded cdt plugin for it, using eclipse's Install Wizard.

My problem is that firstly when I was trying to build C/C++ project, IDE didn't find mingw32-make.exe. After I changed C/C++ project properties in C++ Build, renaming command to build project, it became to work well. But then when I try to Run project I get **"Launch failed. Binary not found"** message.

What did I miss in Eclipse congiguration?

Answer (score 1):

You should add "c:\MinGW\bin" to the Windows path and restart Eclipse.
In windows7 you can right click on "My Computer" hit properties , in "Advanced system settings" then in "Environment variables" then in "System variables" section add ";c:\MinGW\bin" notice the semicolon.
In Windows XP the "Advanced system settings" is not needed.

Comment: MAybe you should setup "Launch Configuration". But as a side note I suggest you get the Code::Blocks the one bundled with MinGW. It is much much easier to setup and run, and the debugger works fine. Whereas Eclipse most likely crash on gdb (unfortunately).